# Worklight 6.1 : navigator.notification.alert is not working in BB10

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10

I am running worklight application on bb10 and using phonegap notification but it is not working throwing error which is

> 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating
>   'navigator.notification.alert' bb10

What is things i am missing in the project , please let me know. I am using webworks 2.0 in my project.

I tried WL.simpleDialog like this

```
WL.SimpleDialog.show(
"My Title", "My Text", 
[{text: "First Button", handler: function() {WL.Logger.debug("First button pressed"); }
}]
)
```

After this also m getting the same error.

> ypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating
>   'navigator.notification.confirm')

Comment: Did you try plain alert(), or WL.SimpleDialog?

Comment: I tried simple alert , it is working. I din't try WL.SinmpleDialog but notification.alert is not working

Comment: See if either of those works for you.

Comment: @IdanAdar , getting the same error . see my updated question.

Comment: @vishal_g have you added the permissison in BB 10.

Comment: how to add this.....why it is required and where to add it. Default permission is there whatever is required.

Comment: This could indicate that the 'cordova*.js' is not being properly loaded. Have you checked the generated index.html (or equivalent html entry point) has all the necessary scripts injected?  (look at the generated file under the 'native/.../www/...' structure)

Comment: Every thing is there thats the reason i am able to call adapter.

Comment: @vishal_g, no there is no udpate. Understand that Stack Overflow is a community owned website. We help when we have the time to help. If you require official IBM support, open a PMR.

Comment: @vishal_g, my understanding is that the development team is in contact with both HDFC and SnapWork so they should be updating you two via email as well as in this question when an update is available. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following plugin needs to be added for the notification dialog to display on BB10 with WebWorks SDK 2.x -

"org.apache.cordova.dialogs"

Before you build and deploy, add this plugin using the command -

webworks plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs